# Seaborn Heatmap Y-tick Labels Stacked

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

I'm working with biological data, and am using the heatmap from Seaborn to plot Pearson R values so I can visually compare expression of each of 22 cell types with every other cell type (making a 22x22 heatmap).

I've had two separate problems. Here is what my plots looked like the other day:

[You can see that in one plot the y-tick labels are spaced, but the last label is clipped off. Then in the other plot, all of the y-tick labels are present, but are spaced too tightly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf1K0.png)

Here's what my plots look like today. I foolishly am not sure what I changed when trying to fix the issue in the first image (aside from changing vmin and vmax, and the color scheme), but now the y-tick labels are all on top of each other.

[The y-ticks are all on top of each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBx0X.png)

Here is my code to generate the heatmaps:

```
def cancerHeatmap(patients, cancer):
    x_labels = ['Naive B','Memory B','Plasma','CD8 T','CD4 T Naive','CD4 T MR',
            'CD4 T MA','FH T','Tregs','GD T',
            'NK resting','NK activated','Monos','Macros M0','Macros M1','Macros M2',
            'Dendritic resting','Dendritic activated','Mast resting','Mast activated','Eosinophils','Neutrophils']
    pearsonrs = getPearsons(patients, cancer)
    axs = sns.heatmap(pearsonrs, cmap = 'RdYlBu', vmin=-0.6, vmax=0.6)
    axs.set_yticklabels(x_labels, rotation = 0, fontsize = 10)
    axs.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation = 90)
    axs.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top') 
    axs.set_xlabel(cancer)
    return axs

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.despine()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,70))
plt.suptitle('Subtitle')
for i, cancer in enumerate(cancer_types):
    print cancer
    plt.subplot((len(cancer_types)/2)+1,2, i+1)
    ax = cancerHeatmap(patients, cancer)
    plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 0.97])
    plt.savefig('outfile.pdf', dpi=200)
```

The important details of this are:

"pearsonrs" is a function that generates the numpy array of all of the values that go directly into the heatmap

"cancer_types" is a list of the different cancer types that I'll be generating heatmaps for

I have no idea why this is happening, especially because I can generate one plot at a time with this code, and the axis are perfect:

```
x_labels = ['Naive B','Memory B','Plasma','CD8 T','CD4 T Naive','CD4 T MR',
            'CD4 T MA','FH T','Tregs','GD T',
            'NK resting','NK activated','Monos','Macros M0','Macros M1','Macros 
            M2', 'Dendritic resting','Dendritic activated','Mast resting','Mast activated','Eosinophils','Neutrophils']
axs = sns.heatmap(np.array(pearsonrs), cmap = 'rainbow', vmin=-0.6, vmax=0.6)
axs.invert_yaxis()
axs.set_yticklabels(x_labels, rotation = 0, fontsize = 10)
axs.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation = 90, fontsize = 10)
axs.set_xlabel('Cancer')
axs.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Edit:
I ran identical scripts on my rMBP and my coworker's rMBP, and mine produced the figures with the stacked axis labels (image 2), and my coworker's computer produced the figures with odd spacing (image 1).

Edit 2: 
It turns out that the Conda installation was slightly different on each computer. Updating both computers to the most recent Conda (4.5.9) does not change the heatmaps that either computer produces.